# Starting a webservice automatically in RedHat

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, redhat

I need to launch a web service automatically on a RedHat server. The web service works and can be loaded manually through NetBeans.

Trying to make it so that the user only needs to perform a single command line or similar to get it running.

Started with getting GlassFish server up and running (used http://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/run_glassfish_v3_as_a mainly, with some input from other sources)

This led to me doing the following;

-Added new user

```
groupadd glassfish

useradd -s /bin/bash -d /home/glassfish -m -g glassfish glassfish
```

-Logged in as said user

```
sudo -i -u glassfish
```

-Installed glassfish

```
cd ~

unzip glassfish-v3.zip

rm glassfish-v3.zip
```

-Left the shell

-Copied in script to /etc/init.d  and configured it as an executable

```
cp <script file as shown below> /etc/init.d/glassfish 

chmod +x /etc/rc.d/init.d/glassfish
```

---

*    THE SCRIPT    *******

---

```
#!/bin/sh
# Platform Services for GlassFish
#
GF_USER=glassfish
GF_HOME=/home/$GF_USER/glassfishv3/glassfish
ASADMIN=$GF_HOME/bin/asadmin
SU="su --login  $GF_USER --command  "

case "$1" in start)
    $SU "$ASADMIN start-domain > /dev/null 2>&1 &";;stop)
    $SU "$ASADMIN stop-domain > /dev/null 2>&1 &";;restart)
    $SU "$ASADMIN restart-domain > /dev/null 2>&1 &";;\*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"esac
```

Can start/stop/restart with;
    sudo /etc/init.d/glassfish start|stop|restart

The problem is, I believe, that Glassfish is running but my little Java web service isn’t. I’m not surprised that the java web service isn’t running as I never included it in the above, but how do I set it up so that my web service is run?

---

I came in this morning and realised that I needed to deploy the java client. I did this by following the instructions from

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/index.html

For deploying applications automatically.

But now using this method my windows web-client can't talk to my RedHat host, but they are perfectly happy when started manually.

The only difference I can think of is that the user on the Redhat machine when starting the services manually is "root" (which is a bit dangerous for a web application). But when starting the client automatically, it runs as a user... Of course this could be a complete red herring....

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deploy your web service as an application](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/index.html) in Glassfish.

Comment: I followed the instructions on your link (very useful by the way, thanks!) as I did realise that when I looked at it this morning. However my client app (on a windows machine) can't talk to the host on the RedHat machine. They talk happily when started manually however... Is this due to using a different user for the web client on the Redhat? (When started manually it's the root user, instead of a basic user)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a war file for your web service, then deploying should be as simple as copying the war file in the `webapps` directory of glassfish.